# Обновить содержимое tinymce в представлении asp net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, tinymce

Настройка редактора выглядит следующим образом

```
// Initialize your tinyMCE Editor with your preferred options
    tinyMCE.init({
        // General options
        mode: "textareas",
        theme: "modern",
        // Theme options
        theme_advanced_buttons1: "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
        theme_advanced_buttons2: "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
        theme_advanced_buttons3: "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
        theme_advanced_buttons4: "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,spellchecker,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,blockquote,pagebreak,|,insertfile,insertimage",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "left",
        theme_advanced_statusbar_location: "bottom",
        theme_advanced_resizing: true,

        // Example content CSS (should be your site CSS)
        content_css: "~/Content/Site.css",
    });
```

Представление, в котором отображается редактор

```
@model Editor.Models.ExampleClass
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Editor"))
{
    <button id="saveDocBtn" type="submit" class="btn btn-lg" style="background-color:green;" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Save boxdoc">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></span>
    </button>
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.HiddenFor(o => o.PathToFile)
    @Html.HiddenFor(o => o.DocTitle)
    <div>
        <!-- This will contain your HtmlContent and use the TinyMCE editor-->
        @Html.TextAreaFor(o => o.HtmlContent, new { rows = 17, id = "tinyTextArea"})
    </div>
}
```

Конроллер, с пом которого сохраняем введенный текст

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(ExampleClass model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try{
                model.WriteToDocFile(model.HtmlContent, byteLimit);                  
                TempData["message"] = "File has been successfully saved.";
            } catch {
                TempData["message"] = "Cant save file. Have some trouble with system.";
            }
        } else {
            TempData["message"] = "Cant save file. Have some trouble with model.";
        }            
        return View(model);
    }
```

Проблема в том, что если размер введенного текста больше какого-то заданного значения мне необходимо обрезать его и сохранить. После сохранения и отправки модели в представление данные находятся в требуемом виде (обрезаны если надо), но в поле текста редактора отображается полный вариант. 
Как правильно реализовать отображение действительных данных в представлении (может как-то удалять кэш редактора) ?

Comment: А вы содержимое в `model.HtmlContent`обрезаете до `byteLimit`? Именно она у вас в редакторе отображается.

Comment: @Fakemind: для вопросов автору используются комментарии. Да, вы их пока не можете оставлять, но на 50 репутации сможете. Пока что преобразовал в комментарий ваш уточняющий вопрос.